# Why binding event is not called after submit button clicked for user control (added code)

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, runtime, repeater

I have a web page that uses single user control and a asp:repeater that uses the same user control and both are created in Page_Load.  Both bahave differently in a submit button clicking event.  The binding event for each of the repeater (depdentBasicInfo)'s user control is called after submit button clicking before page_load.  But the binding event is not for the single user control (spouseBasicInfo).  Why?  Also the user control create a runtime control (assuming a TextBox).  I found there is no way to retrieve the runtime control's Text property after clicking the submit as the control becomes null after PostBack.  How to retrieve the property easily?  Could any one help me?  Thanks.

```
<!--USER CONTROL -->
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PnlSpouseInformation" Visible="true">
<h3 id="ApplicantLabel" runat="server"></h3>
<div class="dependentInformation">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phDependentInformation" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>
</asp:Panel>


<!--  code behind   -->
    public partial class userInfo : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string identity;
    public string  applicantTitle
    {
        set { ApplicantLabel.InnerText = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void Bind()
    {
        WebControl textBox = new TextBox
        {
            Text = identity,
            ID = "textbox"
        };
        phDependentInformation.Controls.Add(textBox);
    }
}
```

---

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title>Test user control binding</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
        <uc1:userInfo runat="server" ID="SpouseBasicInfo" Visible="false" />
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RptDependents"                   OnItemCreated="RptDependents_ItemCreated">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <uc1:userInfo runat="server" ID="DependentBasicInfo" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="submit"      OnClick="OnClickSubmit"><span>Submit</span></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

---

```
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SpouseBasicInfo.identity = "spouse";
            SpouseBasicInfo.Bind();
            SpouseBasicInfo.Visible = true;

            List<String> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("Dependent A");
            list.Add("Dependent B");

            RptDependents.DataSource = list;
            RptDependents.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void OnClickSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsValid)
        {
            return;
        }
        var textbox = SpouseBasicInfo.FindControl("textbox") as TextBox;
        string spouseName = textbox.Text;
    }

    protected void RptDependents_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Item.ItemType)
        {
            case ListItemType.Item:
            case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
                {
                    var dependentInfo = e.Item.DataItem as String;
                    var dependentBasicInfo = e.Item.FindControl("DependentBasicInfo") as userInfo;
                    if (dependentBasicInfo == null) return;
                    dependentBasicInfo.applicantTitle = "Dependent " + (e.Item.ItemIndex + 1);
                    dependentBasicInfo.identity = dependentInfo;
                    dependentBasicInfo.Bind();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your code so we can get a look at it? Also, you say the runtime control becomes null after post back. Is the text property of the control set after the page is rendered? if so you may be able to use a hidden asp label on the page that can hold the text property. When the page is posted back the hidden label still holds the last value held for the text property of said control.

"User control (spouseBasicInfo). Why? Also the user control create a runtime control (assuming a TextBox). I found there is no way to retrieve the runtime control's Text property after clicking the submit as the control becomes null after PostBack. How to retrieve the property easily? Could any one help me? Thanks."

I haven't been working with asp.net for a long time so I don't think I can answer all the questions you are asking. But, if you are creating a text box at runtime and using the placeholder to deliver the object to the screen then yes, the textbox control will be null after post back. This is because it is not an asp.control like a textbox or label that is not runtime created. You can retrieve the value previously held in the text box by creating a label on screen that is hidden. Place your value in the hidden label and the runtime created text box. After post back the hidden label will still hold the value previous to post back and you can retrieve as you would normally retrieve a value held in a control. I hope this helps you get a step closer to solving your issue. Sorry I can't be of more help. Good luck.

Comment: I am very new here and how can I post code?  Thanks.

Comment: Just copy your code and paste it into a reply area.

Comment: I tried that but it says too many chars...actually it is not that long